# LaTeX: Access every character of an string variable

Tags: symbols, strings

I'm using variables to create strings in that way

```
\newcommand{\myText}{2014/12/20}
\myText{}
```

This works great.
Now, I can to access every single character of this string (length is 10), because in other sections of my document I want only get the first four letters ("2014") of it, to create something new.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! TeX doesn't have strings in the sense you mean: you've got a list of ten _tokens_ there :-) Do you want to split on number of tokens or on a delimiter? Can we hard-code the number of tokens and assume the input is long enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Simple Solution

This can be accomplished with the `xstring` package. In particular, the `\StrMid{string}{#2}{#3}` command allows you to take the substring of string from character positions `#2` through `#3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\myText}[2]{\StrMid{2014/12/20}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\myText{1}{4}
\end{document}
```

## Allowing for `\myText{}`

However, the above solution always requires arguments for `\myText`.

It seems you want `\myText{}` to give you the entire string `2014/12/20`. So, we can make the first parameter optional (it defaults to the first position if not given in brackets), and the second parameter is the second position. We set up a conditional so that if the second position is empty, we just get the entire string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\myText}[2][1]{
    \ifx\\#2\\
        {2014/12/20}
    \else
        \StrMid{2014/12/20}{#1}{#2}
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\myText{}

\myText[1]{4} \quad
\myText[6]{7} \quad
\myText[9]{10} \quad

\myText{7} \quad
\myText[6]{10}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks, it works.

Answer (score 7):

With the `stringstrings` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\def\x{2014/12/20}
\substring{\x}{1}{4}\par
\substring{\x}{6}{7}\par
\substring{\x}{9}{$}\par% The $ implies the last character of the string.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternative with the `listofitems` package, set up here to parse the input string on the basis of a `/` separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\def\x{2014/12/20}
\setsepchar[.]{/}
\readlist\mydate{\x}
The year is \mydate[1]\par
The month is \mydate[2]\par
The day is \mydate[3]\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A LuaLaTeX-based solution, which sets up a TeX macro called `\substring` that takes three arguments.

The first argument of the macro `\substring` is a string. It can be either a hard-coded string or a TeX macro that produces a string. E.g., if  `\myText` is defined via `\newcommand{\myText}{2014/12/20}`, then `\myText` could used as the first argument of `\substring`.

The second and third arguments are the starting and ending indexes of the substring and are assumed to be integers. Please indicate if this assumption isn't valid.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\substring[3]{%
    \directlua{ tex.sprint ( string.sub ( "#1", #2, #3 ) ) } }
\begin{document}
\substring{2014/12/20}{1}{4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works too, but I can only accept one answer :)